# How can I run dynamo DB on my local machine with serverless API structure(node js)?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-serverless

I just want to run my serverless apis on local... how can I achieve that...do I need to run dynamoDB locally?? OR we can achieve this without configuring Dynamo on local!!

I was trying with dynamo db local plugin. . . but I want to run dynamo on AWS console...but my serverless apis on my local machine

Comment: What type of framework are you using to deploy your functions/application?

Answer (score 0):

You can use environment variables to specify the AWS access key and secret key that Local should use to connect to the DynamoDB service on AWS.

Comment: I CONFIGURED AWS secret/access key on my local machine. . . . do i need to put anywhere else to connect with dynamo DB . . ?

Comment: am getting forbidden error on  my local machine, when accessing aws apis from serverless offline